# How to check if element contains text with 'while' function, using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some problems!
I need to check some elements for text present. If there is no text - script checks child elements for same. How to do this?
I need to use pure JS.

So here is example:

```
   <div class="parent">
      <div class="first"></div>
      <div class="second">TEXT IS HERE!</div>
       <div class="third"></div>
   </div>
```

Text can be present in ANY of this div`s, so i need to loop through them to find text if it is unavailable in previous.
Thank you!

Comment: The `textContent` of the children is also `textContent` of the parent, i.e. to check if some text is present, check the text content of `.parent`.

Comment: Do you need a reference to the container element of the text, or is it enough to just know, whether there's text in `.parent` or not?

Comment: I just need to check WHERE is the text, in which element

Comment: Okay, and 'where' is that text found? Is it in the `.parent` element, or the `.second` element? Or should it be both?

Comment: It can be generated in any element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PureJS solution you can try it in here http://liveweave.com/XzjGwg
It return an array with each element who contain text

```
function isStrictlyTextNode(node){
  if(node.innerText !== undefined && node.innerText.length > 0 && node.children.length === 0 ) {
    return true;
} else {
  return false;
}

}

function checkForTextInDivs(elementClass){
    var children = document.getElementsByClassName(elementClass)[0].childNodes;
    var nbrChildren = children.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < nbrChildren; i++) {

        if(isStrictlyTextNode(children[i])) {
           $result.push(children[i]);
       }else if(children[i].children !== undefined && children[i].children.length > 0) {
             checkForTextInDivs(children[i].className);
       }
    }
}
$result = [];
checkForTextInDivs('parent', $result);
console.log($result);
```

Comment: @Teemu I updated the code it loop to look if text is present in ANY of the div's